# renderUI not returning graph from javascript to R Shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to create a force graph using javascript within an R shiny application. The code for the app is below.

```
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)
network_data <- jsonlite::read_json("miserables.json")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
    tags$script(src='https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js'),
    titlePanel("force graph example - miserables"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          actionButton(
            "go",
            label = "go"
          )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          p("yo"),
          uiOutput("output_result")
        )
    )
    
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$go, {
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = "jsondata",network_data)
    },ignoreNULL = TRUE,ignoreInit = TRUE)
  output$output_result <- renderUI({
    result <- HTML('<script type="text/javascript", src="fn_canvas.js">  </script>')
    return(result)
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The application is pretty simple. You hit the go button and it sends the [miserables](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4062045?permalink_comment_id=792501) JSON to a javascript file, called `fn_canvas.js`, which should create the force graph. The code for the force graph can be found [here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph-canvas) which I pulled and created this javascript file.

```
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('jsondata', function(message) {
  
  console.log("helllooooo")
  var network_data = message;
  
  function ForceGraph({
    nodes, // an iterable of node objects (typically [{id}, …])
    links // an iterable of link objects (typically [{source, target}, …])
  }, {
    nodeId = d => d.id, // given d in nodes, returns a unique identifier (string)
    nodeGroup, // given d in nodes, returns an (ordinal) value for color
    nodeGroups, // an array of ordinal values representing the node groups
    nodeFill = "currentColor", // node stroke fill (if not using a group color encoding)
    nodeStroke = "#fff", // node stroke color
    nodeStrokeWidth = 1.5, // node stroke width, in pixels
    nodeStrokeOpacity = 1, // node stroke opacity
    nodeRadius = 5, // node radius, in pixels
    nodeStrength,
    linkSource = ({source}) => source, // given d in links, returns a node identifier string
    linkTarget = ({target}) => target, // given d in links, returns a node identifier string
    linkStroke = "#999", // link stroke color
    linkStrokeOpacity = 0.6, // link stroke opacity
    linkStrokeWidth = 1.5, // given d in links, returns a stroke width in pixels
    linkStrokeLinecap = "round", // link stroke linecap
    linkStrength,
    colors = d3.schemeTableau10, // an array of color strings, for the node groups
    width = 640, // outer width, in pixels
    height = 400
    ///, // outer height, in pixels
    ///invalidation // when this promise resolves, stop the simulation,
  } = {}) {
    // Compute values.
    const N = d3.map(nodes, nodeId).map(intern);
    const LS = d3.map(links, linkSource).map(intern);
    const LT = d3.map(links, linkTarget).map(intern);
    const G = nodeGroup == null ? null : d3.map(nodes, nodeGroup).map(intern);
    const W = typeof linkStrokeWidth !== "function" ? null : d3.map(links, linkStrokeWidth);
    const L = typeof linkStroke !== "function" ? null : d3.map(links, linkStroke);
  
    // Replace the input nodes and links with mutable objects for the simulation.
    nodes = d3.map(nodes, (_, i) => ({id: N[i]}));
    links = d3.map(links, (_, i) => ({source: LS[i], target: LT[i]}));
  
    // Compute default domains.
    if (G && nodeGroups === undefined) nodeGroups = d3.sort(G);
  
    // Construct the scales.
    const color = nodeGroup == null ? null : d3.scaleOrdinal(nodeGroups, colors);
  
    // Construct the forces.
    const forceNode = d3.forceManyBody();
    const forceLink = d3.forceLink(links).id(({index: i}) => N[i]);
    if (nodeStrength !== undefined) forceNode.strength(nodeStrength);
    if (linkStrength !== undefined) forceLink.strength(linkStrength);
  
    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force("link", forceLink)
      .force("charge", forceNode)
      .force("center",  d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2))
      .on("tick", ticked);
  
    /// Is it ok to do the below??!
    function context2d(width, height, dpi) {
      if (dpi == null) dpi = devicePixelRatio;
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = width * dpi;
      canvas.height = height * dpi;
      canvas.style.width = width + "px";
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.scale(dpi, dpi);
      return context;
    }
  
    const context = context2d(width, height);
    ///const context = DOM.context2d(width, height);
  
    function ticked() {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  
      context.save();
      context.globalAlpha = linkStrokeOpacity;
      for (const [i, link] of links.entries()) { 
        context.beginPath();        
        drawLink(link);
        context.strokeStyle = L ? L[i]: linkStroke;
        context.lineWidth = W ? W[i]: linkStrokeWidth;
        context.stroke();
      }
      context.restore();
  
      context.save();
      context.strokeStyle = nodeStroke;
      context.globalAlpha = nodeStrokeOpacity;
      for (const [i, node] of nodes.entries()) {
        context.beginPath();
        drawNode(node) 
        context.fillStyle = G ? color(G[i]): nodeFill;
        context.strokeStyle = nodeStroke;
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();
      }
      context.restore();
    }
  
    function drawLink(d) {
      context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
      context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
    }
  
    function drawNode(d) {
      context.moveTo(d.x + nodeRadius, d.y);
      context.arc(d.x, d.y, nodeRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    }  
  
    ///if (invalidation != null) invalidation.then(() => simulation.stop());
  
    function intern(value) {
      return value !== null && typeof value === "object" ? value.valueOf() : value;
    }
  
    function drag(simulation) {    
      function dragstarted(event) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
        event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
      }
      
      function dragged(event) {
        event.subject.fx = event.x;
        event.subject.fy = event.y;
      }
      
      function dragended(event) {
        if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        event.subject.fx = null;
        event.subject.fy = null;
      }
  
      function dragsubject(event) {
        return simulation.find(event.sourceEvent.offsetX, event.sourceEvent.offsetY);
      }
      
      return d3.drag()
        .subject(dragsubject)
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended);
    }
  
    console.log("finished")
    return Object.assign(d3.select(context.canvas).call(drag(simulation)).node(), {scales: {color}});
    
  }
  
  chart = ForceGraph(network_data, {
    nodeId: (d) => d.id,
    nodeGroup: (d) => d.group,
    linkStrokeWidth: (l) => Math.sqrt(l.value),  
    width: 600,
    height: 600
    ///,
    ///invalidation, // a promise to stop the simulation when the cell is re-run
  })
  return chart
  
});
```

Once you hit the go button in the application, the force graph should be returned from the javascript file. However, currently nothing is returned from the file. I even print console messages which say the code was run. I'm not sure whether there is an issue with my R code or the javascript code. Any help appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: while you can communicate between JS and R (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html ), it might be simpler to use the corresponding HTML widget: https://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_networkD3.html

Comment: I was using that previously. I have a lot of data though which is why I wanted to use the canvas version of the force network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `return chart;` with `$("body").append(chart);`. The `chart` object is a canvas element, and this code inserts it in the body element.

Put this file ***fn_canvas.js*** in the **www** subfolder of your app.

Include it in your app as follows:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src='https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js'),
    tags$script(src = 'fn_canvas.js')
  ),
  titlePanel("force graph example - miserables"),
  ......
```

Remove the `renderUI` and the `uiOutput`.

Comment: Won’t this only run once though? When the app is initialized. I want the network to update based on changes in input values.

Comment: Actually all I had to do was change the `return chart;` argument and it fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @AyeTown No, it will not run only once. You just have to include this script once, and you can use it as many times as you want.